# I am noticing a malicious DNS query in Thunderbird

Tags: suricata, thunderbird

My Suricata IDS is generating this alert when starting Thunderbird:

```
ET INFO Observed DNS Query to .cloud TLD
```

You can analyze a json log:

```
{
  "_index": "suricata-1.1.0-2022.02.11",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "Uvxd6X4Bz6KASDsJzj8a",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "src_autonomous_system": "private",
    "src_ip": "192.168.x.x",
    "dest_port": 53,
    "server_autonomous_system": "private",
    "ip_version": "IPv4",
    "dns": {
      "query": [
        {
          "rrname": "prod-tp.sumo.mozit.cloud",
          "type": "query",
          "rrtype": "AAAA",
          "tx_id": 0,
          "id": 53408
        }
      ]
    },
    "src_hostname": "192.168.x.x",
    "app_proto": "dns",
    "client_autonomous_system": "private",
    "flow": {
      "bytes_toclient": 0,
      "bytes_toserver": 84,
      "pkts_toclient": 0,
      "bytes": 84,
      "start": "2022-02-11T15:19:04.496Z",
      "pkts_toserver": 1,
      "pkts": 1
    },
    "log": {
      "severity": "critical"
    },
    "server_ip": "192.168.1.1",
    "event": {
      "host": "laboratory-host",
      "type": "suricata",
      "subtype": "alert"
    },
    "node": {
      "ipaddr": "10.0.x.x",
      "hostname": "laboratory-host"
    },
    "alert": {
      "action": "allowed",
      "signature": "ET INFO Observed DNS Query to .cloud TLD",
      "rev": 4,
      "gid": 1,
      "severity": 2,
      "signature_id": 2027865,
      "metadata": {
        "deployment": [
          "Perimeter"
        ],
        "former_category": [
          "INFO"
        ],
        "affected_product": [
          "Any"
        ],
        "signature_severity": [
          "Major"
        ],
        "created_at": [
          "2019_08_13"
        ],
        "attack_target": [
          "Client_Endpoint"
        ],
        "updated_at": [
          "2020_09_17"
        ]
      },
      "category": "Potentially Bad Traffic"
    },
    "dest_port_name": "dns (UDP/53)",
    "service_port": "53",
    "in_iface": "enp3s0",
    "@timestamp": "2022-02-11T15:19:04.496Z",
    "tx_id": 0,
    "traffic_locality": "private",
    "server_hostname": "192.168.1.1",
    "proto": "UDP",
    "service_name": "dns (UDP/53)",
    "client_ip": "192.168.x.x",
    "vlan": "0",
    "client_hostname": "192.168.x.x",
    "src_port": 43105,
    "tags": [],
    "dest_hostname": "192.168.1.1",
    "tcp_flags": "none",
    "flow_id": 1282324736546066,
    "dest_ip": "192.168.1.1",
    "dest_autonomous_system": "private",
    "host": {
      "ip": [
        "192.168.x.x",
        (...) 
      ],
      "id": "f8e52e34aea14e72bdb8300859e5c7a9",
      "hostname": "laboratory-host",
      "os": {
        "codename": "focal",
        "family": "debian",
        "name": "Ubuntu",
        "platform": "ubuntu",
        "version": "20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)",
        "kernel": "5.4.0-99-generic"
      },
      "architecture": "x86_64",
      "mac": [
       (...)
      ],
      "containerized": false
    },
    "@version": "1.1.0",
    "src_port_name": "UDP/43105"
  },
  "fields": {
    "flow.start": [
      "2022-02-11T15:19:04.496Z"
    ],
    "@timestamp": [
      "2022-02-11T15:19:04.496Z"
    ],
    "tls.notbefore": [],
    "flow.end": [],
    "tls.notafter": []
  }
}
```

Wireshark capture shows:

```
    Queries
        support.mozilla.org: type AAAA, class IN
            Name: support.mozilla.org
            [Name Length: 19]
            [Label Count: 3]
            Type: AAAA (IPv6 Address) (28)
            Class: IN (0x0001)
    Answers
        support.mozilla.org: type CNAME, class IN, cname prod-tp.sumo.mozit.cloud
            Name: support.mozilla.org
            Type: CNAME (Canonical NAME for an alias) (5)
            Class: IN (0x0001)
            Time to live: 60 (1 minute)
            Data length: 26
            CNAME: prod-tp.sumo.mozit.cloud


    Queries
        prod-tp.sumo.mozit.cloud: type AAAA, class IN
            Name: prod-tp.sumo.mozit.cloud
            [Name Length: 24]
            [Label Count: 4]
            Type: AAAA (IPv6 Address) (28)
            Class: IN (0x0001)
    Authoritative nameservers
        sumo.mozit.cloud: type SOA, class IN, mname ns-1513.awsdns-61.org
            Name: sumo.mozit.cloud
            Type: SOA (Start Of a zone of Authority) (6)
            Class: IN (0x0001)
            Time to live: 358 (5 minutes, 58 seconds)
            Data length: 73
            Primary name server: ns-1513.awsdns-61.org
            Responsible authority's mailbox: awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com
            Serial Number: 1
            Refresh Interval: 7200 (2 hours)
            Retry Interval: 900 (15 minutes)
            Expire limit: 1209600 (14 days)
            Minimum TTL: 86400 (1 day)
```

Maybe it is a false positive? It is a conventional query from support.mozilla.org?
Interesting, searching in internet it appears reported also in a Chrome's request:
https://www.joesandbox.com/analysis/335163/0/html
...and a iexplorer:
https://any.run/report/f2ef2560f02aff409bc72d60fff432529d6ae2b63c862edc5c85ae11b8e3d7e2/ff2e1109-1e49-4bba-9196-534d455fb895

Versión:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0 Thunderbird/91.5.0
```

My syslogs:

```
Feb 11 12:59:05 localhost thunderbird.desktop[127832]: ###!!! [Parent][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost
Feb 11 12:59:05 localhost systemd[2078]: gnome-launched-thunderbird.desktop-127832.scope: Succeeded.
Feb 11 12:59:15 localhost systemd[2078]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Feb 11 12:59:15 localhost thunderbird.desktop[128356]: [calBackendLoader] Using Thunderbird's libical backend
Feb 11 12:59:15 localhost thunderbird.desktop[128356]: [LDAPModuleLoader] Using LDAPDirectory.jsm
Feb 11 12:59:15 localhost thunderbird.desktop[128356]: [MsgSendModuleLoader] Using MessageSend.jsm
Feb 11 12:59:15 localhost thunderbird.desktop[128356]: [SmtpModuleLoader] Using SmtpService.jsm
Feb 11 12:59:17 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Feb 11 12:59:17 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: message repeated 5 times: [ Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.]
Feb 11 12:59:17 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: Successfully made thread 128461 of process 128356 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Feb 11 12:59:17 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.
Feb 11 12:59:17 localhost thunderbird.desktop[128356]: console.debug: "Trying to load /usr/lib/thunderbird/libotr.so"
Feb 11 12:59:17 localhost thunderbird.desktop[128356]: console.debug: "Trying to load libotr.so from system's standard library locations"
Feb 11 12:59:17 localhost thunderbird.desktop[128356]: console.debug: "Trying to load libotr.so.5 from system's standard library locations"
Feb 11 12:59:17 localhost thunderbird.desktop[128356]: console.debug: "Successfully loaded OTR library libotr.so.5 from system's standard library locations"
Feb 11 12:59:17 localhost thunderbird.desktop[128356]: console.debug: "Successfully loaded OpenPGP library librnp.so version 0.15.2+git20210806.dd923a4e.MZLA from /usr/lib/thunderbird/librnp.so"
Feb 11 12:59:17 localhost thunderbird.desktop[128356]: console.debug: "Found 12 public keys and 6 secret keys (6 protected, 0 unprotected)"
Feb 11 12:59:17 localhost thunderbird.desktop[128356]: console.debug: "Successfully loaded optional OpenPGP library libgpgme.so.11 from system's standard library locations"
Feb 11 12:59:17 localhost thunderbird.desktop[128356]: console.debug: "gpgme version: 1.13.1-unknown"
Feb 11 12:59:17 localhost thunderbird.desktop[128356]: console.warn: services.settings: thunderbird/hijack-blocklists has signature disabled
Feb 11 12:59:18 localhost thunderbird.desktop[128356]: JavaScript warning: resource://gre/modules/Troubleshoot.jsm, line 696: WebGL context was lost.
Feb 11 12:59:18 localhost thunderbird.desktop[128356]: JavaScript warning: resource://gre/modules/Troubleshoot.jsm, line 696: WebGL context was lost.
Feb 11 12:59:18 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.
Feb 11 12:59:18 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: message repeated 3 times: [ Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.]
Feb 11 12:59:18 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: Successfully made thread 128478 of process 128356 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Feb 11 12:59:18 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.
Feb 11 12:59:23 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: message repeated 6 times: [ Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.]
Feb 11 12:59:23 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: Successfully made thread 128562 of process 128489 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Feb 11 12:59:23 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 2 users.
Feb 11 12:59:26 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: message repeated 10 times: [ Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 2 users.]
Feb 11 12:59:37 localhost thunderbird.desktop[128624]: [GFX1-]: Failed to connect WebRenderBridgeChild.
Feb 11 12:59:37 localhost thunderbird.desktop[128624]: [GFX1-]: Failed to connect WebRenderBridgeChild.
Feb 11 12:59:38 localhost thunderbird.desktop[128489]: ###!!! [Parent][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost
Feb 11 12:59:39 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.
Feb 11 12:59:39 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: message repeated 5 times: [ Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.]
Feb 11 12:59:39 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: Successfully made thread 128865 of process 128782 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Feb 11 12:59:39 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 2 users.
Feb 11 12:59:41 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: message repeated 10 times: [ Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 2 users.]
Feb 11 12:59:58 localhost thunderbird.desktop[128356]: ###!!! [Parent][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost
Feb 11 12:59:58 localhost systemd[2078]: gnome-launched-thunderbird.desktop-128356.scope: Succeeded.
Feb 11 12:59:59 localhost systemd[2078]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Feb 11 13:00:00 localhost thunderbird.desktop[129098]: [calBackendLoader] Using Thunderbird's libical backend
Feb 11 13:00:00 localhost thunderbird.desktop[129098]: [LDAPModuleLoader] Using LDAPDirectory.jsm
Feb 11 13:00:00 localhost thunderbird.desktop[129098]: [MsgSendModuleLoader] Using MessageSend.jsm
Feb 11 13:00:00 localhost thunderbird.desktop[129098]: [SmtpModuleLoader] Using SmtpService.jsm
Feb 11 13:00:01 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Feb 11 13:00:01 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: message repeated 5 times: [ Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.]
Feb 11 13:00:01 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: Successfully made thread 129212 of process 129098 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Feb 11 13:00:01 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.
Feb 11 13:00:02 localhost thunderbird.desktop[129098]: console.debug: "Trying to load /usr/lib/thunderbird/libotr.so"
Feb 11 13:00:02 localhost thunderbird.desktop[129098]: console.debug: "Trying to load libotr.so from system's standard library locations"
Feb 11 13:00:02 localhost thunderbird.desktop[129098]: console.debug: "Trying to load libotr.so.5 from system's standard library locations"
Feb 11 13:00:02 localhost thunderbird.desktop[129098]: console.debug: "Successfully loaded OTR library libotr.so.5 from system's standard library locations"
Feb 11 13:00:02 localhost thunderbird.desktop[129098]: console.debug: "Successfully loaded OpenPGP library librnp.so version 0.15.2+git20210806.dd923a4e.MZLA from /usr/lib/thunderbird/librnp.so"
Feb 11 13:00:02 localhost thunderbird.desktop[129098]: console.debug: "Found 12 public keys and 6 secret keys (6 protected, 0 unprotected)"
Feb 11 13:00:02 localhost thunderbird.desktop[129098]: console.debug: "Successfully loaded optional OpenPGP library libgpgme.so.11 from system's standard library locations"
Feb 11 13:00:02 localhost thunderbird.desktop[129098]: console.debug: "gpgme version: 1.13.1-unknown"
Feb 11 13:00:02 localhost thunderbird.desktop[129098]: console.warn: services.settings: thunderbird/hijack-blocklists has signature disabled
Feb 11 13:00:03 localhost thunderbird.desktop[129098]: JavaScript warning: resource://gre/modules/Troubleshoot.jsm, line 696: WebGL context was lost.
Feb 11 13:00:03 localhost thunderbird.desktop[129098]: JavaScript warning: resource://gre/modules/Troubleshoot.jsm, line 696: WebGL context was lost.
Feb 11 13:00:03 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.
Feb 11 13:00:03 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: message repeated 3 times: [ Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.]
Feb 11 13:00:03 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: Successfully made thread 129246 of process 129098 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Feb 11 13:00:03 localhost rtkit-daemon[1577]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a legitimate Mozilla domain. If a security tool tells you that a domain is malicious just because it's under the .cloud TLD, then you should uninstall said tool, and demand your money back if it wasn't free.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We are talking about a open-source community Emerging Threats. Obviously this rule needs to be commented out for this local machine.

Comment: The rule is doing what it is designed, to detect anomalous DNS queries. Queries to .cloud TLDs are not common. You can set this rule to alert but not block the traffic, which is how my IPS is set up when dealing with DNS alerts